# PowerPoint loop for specific slide numbers

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

I have number of slide sets with Excel charts that need to be formatted to be better displayed in PPT (increase font size).

I figured out the code below but can't a way to insert loop so this code is only applied to slides 36 to 45.

I've tried the following code below but doesn't work, I think it's because it references ActivePresentation whilst my formatting code references ActiveWindow but I don't have enought PPT VBA knowledge to fix that.

```
Dim oPresentation As Presentation
Set oPresentation = ActivePresentation

Dim oSlide As Slide
Dim oSlides As SlideRange
Dim oShape As Shape
Dim slideNumber As Integer

For slideNumber = 36 To 45

 >>>REST OF MY CODE INSERTED HERE<<<

Next slideNumber
```

---

```
Sub FormatChartPPT()

'PURPOSE: Increase font size of chart data labels, legend, axes values and categories

Dim ocht As Chart
Dim i As Integer
Dim shp As Shape


'Auto select chart
  For Each shp In ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes
    With shp
      If .HasChart Then .Select
   End With
  Next shp


'Apply to selected chart
Set ocht = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Chart


'Format data labels
For i = 1 To ocht.SeriesCollection.Count

If ocht.SeriesCollection(i).HasDataLabels Then

With ocht.SeriesCollection(i).DataLabels.Font
.Size = 14
End With

End If

Next i


'Format legend
If ocht.HasLegend Then
With ocht.Legend.Font
.Size = 14
End With
End If

'Format axis values
With ocht.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font
.Size = 14
End With

'Format axis category
With ocht.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font
.Size = 14
End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new method that takes a slide and formats the shapes on it as desired. Say we define it as `Sub FormatShapes(sld As Slide)` (see code later). This method should then be called in your main loop, e.g.:

```
For SlideNumber = 36 To 45
    FormatShapes ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNumber)
Next SlideNumber
```

FormatShapes could look like this:

```
Sub FormatShapes(sld As Slide)
    Dim ocht As Chart
    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasChart Then
            Set ocht = shp.Chart
            ... Do shape chart formatting using ocht ...
        End If
    Next shp
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I wasn't aware of such method but this works perfectly !